Matrix derivation of the sum of two function
if I have a scaler in terms of matrices $s = f(X) + g(X)$. where $f$ and $g$ are functions of matrices. I want to take the derivative of $s$ in terms of $X$,  derivative of $f$ in terms of $X$ and the derivative of $g$ in terms of $X$ not compatible in size. Assume they both result in matrices how I can deal with such problem.

what does "$X$ not compatible in size" mean? Taking the derivative of a scalar-valued function $f$ wrt a matrix $X$ yields a matrix, often denoted by $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}f$

it means that after derivative of f(X) and g(X) the dimension of derivative is not the same, Thus, I cannot sum the derivative

this is impossible. Say $X$ is a $n\times k$ matrix. The $i,j$ element in $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}f$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}g$ tells you how $f$ and $g$, respectively, change when the $i,j$ element of $X$ changes. By construction $f$ and $g$ both depend on $X$, so it's impossible that the derivative does not depend on some of the elements
